Firefox Profile in Selenium
I am trying to access a site and use my current Firefox profile so I do not get prompted to enable location services. I have looked all around and can't find a direct solution to my problem. This is the current code I have:
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from time import sleep

fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile('C:\Users\tommy\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\jfrxn7d4.default-release')

driver = webdriver.Firefox(fp)

driver.get("https://www.google.com/")

**Error Message I receive:
**
  File "C:\Users\tommy\OneDrive\Desktop\Proj\Task\FirstTry", line 5
    fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile('C:\Users\tommy\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\jfrxn7d4.default-release')
                                                                                                                    ^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

I have tried different ways to reach the path to my firefox profile and open it, but nothing seems to work.

that's a problem with the path string, use forward slashes instead, check this for more options.
